# WebDev Issue when works with Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a Nhibernate Class Library and a Web App that references it. I can get data form the Product table and It's fine, but when I refresh it, I receive this issue.Please see image below:

<strike>http://vi-vn.com/pubs/images/NhibernateWeb.jpg</strike> (Dead Link)

Is there a way to correct his issue?

Comment: How should anyone know what the problem is? You should debug your server and provide the exception that occurred and the code that produces it.

Comment: http://vi-vn.com/pubs/images/SessionClose.jpg
Yes it. I use NHibernate-2.1.0.Alpha2-bin

Comment: For another time, there is a tiny but useful link at the bottom of the exception window that says "Copy exception detail to the clipboard". When clicking on this you get the stack trace, inner exception, error message and all you need as simple text to paste somewhere, eg. to a stackoverflow question. Most of the time a piece of code is also useful. Otherwise people have to guess what you are doing, you get not the answers you need or not any at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message images you have linked indicate to me that you are probably attempting to access a session after it has already been closed. This commonly occurs when trying to access lazy-loaded collections/references. For example:

```
class MyObject
{
    public virtual IList<MyOtherObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}

MyObject obj = session.Load<MyObject>(1);

// Some stuff happens, the session is explicitly closed or goes out of scope

// Later, obj is still tied to the (now closed) session but code tries to:
int count = obj.MyObjects.Count; // MyObjects is lazy-loaded, NHibernate tries to query
```

NHibernate sees that the MyObjects collection is lazy-loaded and has not been initialized yet, so it tries to query for the collection via the session that it is associated with. However, that session is already closed so it throws an `ObjectDisposedException` and says "Session is closed!"

The solution is to either pre-load your collection or make sure the session does not go out of scope or is explicitly disposed before you are done with it.